# Error handler not called until after all retries are attempted in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka, spring-retry

I am trying to write an error handler for my spring cloud stream application; however, the error handler is only called after all retries have been attempted. Is there a way to catch each exception and process them individually instead of waiting for the retries to be exhausted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "process" ?

The whole point of retry is to retry failures until successful or retries are exhausted.

That said, you can wire up your own `RetryTemplate` as [described here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.SR1/reference/htmlsingle/#_retry_template) and add a `RetryListener` to it so you can be notified of each failure.

Comment: By "process" I mean that I'm writing the results to a DB and would like to retry the operation again.

Comment: Also, I was looking at https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/ for docs. Is this not the latest documentation? That section you refer to does not appear in this doc.

Comment: Looks like that link is stale; it's always best to start at [the project page](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/).

Comment: I fixed the "current" link but it will take some time for the cache to expire.